# ASP.NET Core Code Generator doesn't work with DI groups

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, startup

**dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller doesn't work with DI**

When inject directly dependencies in Program.cs file.
But get error register groups of services with extension methods

When program has few dependencies need to inject in Program.cs, with following injection I still can use `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller` to generate code :

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ISupportManager, SupportManager>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new QRCodeService(new QRCodeGenerator()));
```

**But when program get bigger with the need of multiple DI, I move them to group of Dependencies by following code:**

```cs
namespace LinkU.Configurations
{
      public static class ConfigureCoreServices
      {
            public static IServiceCollection AddMyDependencyGroup(
                 this IServiceCollection services)
            {
                  services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
                  services.AddSingleton(new QRCodeService(new QRCodeGenerator()));

                  services.AddTransient<ISupportManager, SupportManager>();
                  services.AddScoped<IDepartmentManager, DepartmentManager>();
                  services.AddScoped<IJobOpeningManager, JobOpeningManager>();

                  return services;
            }
      }
}
```

**and register in Program.cs by following code:**

```cs
builder.Services.AddMyDependencyGroup();
```

**Then I get following error:**

```bash
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...

Minimal hosting scenario!
Attempting to compile the application in memory.
Could not get the reflection type for DbContext : LinkU.Areas.Identity.Data.AppIdentityDbContext
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:06.50
```

I don't know if this problem is due to Identity model configuration or not, but JobOpening, Department and Support model related to IdentityDbContext class in my program:

```
public partial class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JobOpening> JobOpenings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Support> Supports { get; set; }


}
```

> This's guide link by Microsoft to [Register groups of services with extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#register-groups-of-services-with-extension-methods)

Comment: In  your ConfigureCoreServices , try to change `builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();` into `services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();` since you  move them to group of Dependencies. Besides, from the document , it use `builder.Services
    .AddConfig(builder.Configuration).AddMyDependencyGroup();
` ,but you use `builder.Services.AddWebServices().AddMyDependencyGroup();` Why do you use  AddWebServices() ?

Comment: Do you try to use group of Dependencies with removing the `services.AddScoped<IDepartmentManager, DepartmentManager>(); services.AddScoped<IJobOpeningManager, JobOpeningManager>();` ? Does it  meet the error ?

Comment: Sorry, it's a copy paste error. I've edited code as I done.

Comment: I've tried to register only Email and QR services in this method for meeting same type requirement as Microsoft recommended but it doesn't work, though

Comment: Have you check [dotnet aspnet-codegenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-8.0) ?   I don't see the usage like dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller to generate code. The document like: dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name MoviesController -m Movie -dc MvcMovie.Data.MvcMovieContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries --databaseProvider sqlite

Comment: I explored that the problem comes from Extension method for IServiceCollection. But I do not have solution to resolve this problem. I think above extension method create to different instances. So it leads to conflict with first instance in Program.cs